# How can I update ngx-timeago language on button press?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, localization

I needed to localize the ngx-timeago. It works fine, but I don't know how to change from Deutch to Spanish when pressing a button.

This the template:

```
{{ date | timeago:live}}

<div class="btn">Change Language</div>
```

This is the code of my Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { TimeagoModule, TimeagoIntl, TimeagoFormatter, TimeagoCustomFormatter } from 'ngx-timeago';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, TimeagoModule.forRoot({formatter: { provide: 
  TimeagoFormatter, useClass: TimeagoCustomFormatter },})
],
providers: [TimeagoIntl],
declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And this is the code of my Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { strings as stringsDe } from 'ngx-timeago/language-strings/de';
import { strings as stringsEs } from 'ngx-timeago/language-strings/es';
import { TimeagoIntl } from 'ngx-timeago';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(intl: TimeagoIntl) {
    intl.strings = stringsEs;
    intl.changes.next();
  }
  name = 'Angular';
  date = new Date();
}
```

I created a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qkipez?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `(click)` on the button and bind accordingly:

```
<div class="btn" (click)="changeLang()">Change Language</div>
```

in **component**:

```
  changeLang(){
    this.intl.strings = stringsEs;
    this.intl.changes.next();
  }
```

Try this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ezajwh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Doing like this will result in compiler warning ```CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts```

Comment: ```Warning: component.ts depends on 'ngx-timeago/language-strings/ru'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies``` 
See link: https://web.dev/commonjs-larger-bundles/
As mentioned: **CommonJS was not designed with reducing the production bundle size in mind** and your way of suppressing warnings instead of fixing them to lower production bundle size.